# javascript: Error with css-loader starting up webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I keep getting the error below when I try to run `npm run dev`.  I have tried to dump my node modules and `npm install` again but to no luck.  I also tried to reinstall webpack but same result.  I also tried deleting the `package-lock.json` so that it would rebuild, but again nothing.  I included my package.json contents and webpack config contents below the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!./src/index.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, esModule? }
    at validate (/Users/coding/my-webpack-app/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:104:11)
    at Object.loader (/Users/coding/my-webpack-app/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:36:29)
 @ ./src/index.css 2:12-97 9:17-24 13:15-22
 @ multi ./src/index.js ./src/index.css
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-webpack-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "start": "webpack -p && node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js',
    './src/index.css'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "script-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`localIdentName` and `minimize` are not an available options on `css-loader`

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#options